# Excel VBA conditional drop downs in multiple rows should affect the 5 cells in front of it

Tags: excel, vba

I have a drop down in cell A1 with options yes or no. When I select yes nothing should happen but when i select "no" cell B1 to G1 should colour grey and also get locked.

I have a code which i used to have this effect on one row,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Range("A1") = "Yes" Then
        Range("B1:D1").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    ElseIf Range("A1") = "No" Then
        Range("B1:D1").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    End If


End Sub
```

I want to replicate this from A1 to A15. For example if I am selecting NO in cell A7 then B7 to D7 should colour grey, also want the locking code in the similar manner,

Any help is much appreciated,

Thanks
Abi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the row that have been changed by using `Target.Row`. Check out this solution:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:A15")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        If Range("A" & Target.Row) = "Yes" Then
            Range("B" & Target.Row & ":D" & Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        ElseIf Range("A" & Target.Row) = "No" Then
            Range("B" & Target.Row & ":D" & Target.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much.. works a treat.. also can you help me with how to disable or lock the highlighted cells as i don want anyone to enter data there....

Comment: Well, basically you need to show which cells should be locked and which should not by `Range(...).Locked = True/False`, and then protect worksheet by `Sheets(...).Protect` and unprotect it with `Sheets(...).Unprotect` when you need to change something. This functions have some specific parameters. For  more details, please google it or create another thread, with more specific request. By the way, if my solution worked for you, please accept it as an answer by clicking this tick mark on the left of my post ;) .